# How to use Auto Layout to stick a view from the right to the left of the screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

In Xcode with Swift and Auto Layout.

I placed a MapView to and applied Auto Layout constraints :

Trailing Space to superview: Equals 0

Leading Space to superview: Equals 0

but these leave a space of 16px on each side. So I changed them to:

Trailing Space to superview: Equals -16

Leading Space to superview: Equals -16

That worked just fine for iPhone 6, but when I tested it with iPhone 6 Plus I found a space of 4px on each side. If I changed my constraints to -20s then for the iPhone 6 the two 4px will be hidden.

Is there a way to stick a view to the edge for both devices using Auto Layout without specifying pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Uncheck** `Constrain to margins` in the "Pin" dialog, and use 0 as left/right space:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use size classes,then add new constraints,problem solved!!